# What's the name of this UIControl?

Tags: ios, uicontrol, ios7

What's the UIControl used in this pic?
Is it a UITableView with another control on the bottom?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It looks like a table view in edit state. The cell with the green plus is in add editing style.

Comment: @dasdom This is the control used in the address book on iOS7. So I can enable the editing state as default state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet this is a `UITableView` with a custom cell for the Add Phone button.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a different type of cell in the last row, or a separate control below the table.

Answer (score 0):

may be footer view of UITableView

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a table view in edit state. The cell with the green plus is in add editing style.

I think you get this when you return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` from `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`